# Можно ли одновременно изменить размеры компонентов внутри компонента при входе в полноэкранный режим?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

[image: свернутое окно]
[image: развернутое окно]

Возможно ли одновременно расширить все компоненты при развертывании в полноэкранный режим, находящиеся в `ScrollBox`, и при свертывании вернуть размеры? Знаю, как прописать для одного, но компонентов там много.

Comment: Установите Anchors контролов [право, лево, верх] и они сами расширятся.

Comment: @Igor не уверен, что в D7 есть якоря... Возможно, там только align

Comment: @kami - Насколько я помню, они уже в Delphi 6 были.

Comment: @Igor тогда сделаете ответом? Кстати, если в D7 есть TVertScrollBox, то можно вообще сделать всем компонентам Align = alTop, выставить Margins и забыть об этом :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите `Anchors` контролов `[право, лево, верх]` и они сами расширятся.

Обратите внимание на предложение @kami.